# Python Pandas заполнить датафрейм данными из другого датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas

Есть сгруппированный датафрейм, в котором хранятся пары уникальных чисел и счетчик с количеством повторений каждой пары.
Дополнительно есть 2 колонки, в которых храниться каждое число из пары.

[image: первый DF]

Так же имеется второй датафрейм, в котором есть числа.

[image: Второй DF для заполнения]

Что необходимо: во второй датафрейм добавить 2 колонки, в в каждую из которых будут внесены 2 числа, с которыми указанное число было в паре максимальное количество раз в первом df.

Пробовал написать функцию:
берет число из второй таблицы
использует его в качестве маски для отбора строк из первого датафрейма.
Так как первый df отсортирован по убыванию совпадений, то верхние 2 строки с примененной маской будут содержать совпадение и всегда будут самыми популярными: первая строка для получения первой рекомендации, вторая строка - для второй

Далее пытаюсь вернуть число != поданному:
если поданное число в колонке first, то возвращаем second, иначе возвращаем first.
Вот кусок кода без условий разбивки 2 строки, только с одной.
Мне бы понять: как его заставить работать?)))

```
def get_rec(n):
    mask1 = recomedations['first'] == n
    mask2 = recomedations['second'] == n
    temprec = recomedations[mask1 | mask2].head(1)
    if temprec['first'] == n:
        return temprec['second']
    else:
        return temprec['first']
```

Comment: Исходные данные приведите в воспроизводимом виде. и покажите желаемый результат.

Answer (score 1):

Исходные данные для примера:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'pairs': [(551, 566), (515, 551), (489, 551), (523, 551), (566, 794)],
                   'first': [566, 551, 551, 551, 794],
                    'second': [551, 515, 489, 523, 566],
                    'count': [797, 417, 311, 304, 290]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'resource_id': list(range(356, 1201))})
```

Решение:

```
df1_filt = df1.groupby('first')['count'].nlargest(2).droplevel(1).reset_index()
keys = list(df1_filt.columns.values)
i1 = df1.set_index(keys).index
i2 = df1_filt.set_index(keys).index
df1_filt = df1[i1.isin(i2)]

df1_filt['numb'] = df1_filt.groupby('first').cumcount()+1

final = df2.merge(df1_filt.pivot(index='first', columns='numb', values='second'),
                  left_on='resource_id', right_on='first')
```

Вывод для пример:

```
print(final)

   resource_id      1      2
0          551  515.0  489.0
1          566  551.0    NaN
2          794  566.0    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

при исходных

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'pairs': [(489, 566), (515, 551), (489, 551), (523, 551), (566, 794)],
                   'first': [566, 551, 551, 551, 794],
                    'second': [489, 515, 489, 523, 566],
                    'count': [797, 417, 311, 304, 290]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'resource_id': list(range(489, 794))})
```

можно так попробовать:

```
res = df2["resource_id"].apply(lambda x: [df1[["first", "second"]]
                                          .iloc[i,j-2] for i, j in np.argwhere(df1==x)[:2]])
df2[[1,2]] = pd.DataFrame(res.to_list(), index = df2.index)
```

df2 теперь:

```
     resource_id      1      2
0            489  566.0  551.0
1            490    NaN    NaN
 ...
25           514    NaN    NaN
26           515  551.0    NaN
27           516    NaN    NaN
 ...
33           522    NaN    NaN
34           523  551.0    NaN
и т. д.
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариация на тему. Алгоритм, наверное, похож на подход @KirillKondratenko, но другая реализация и другой результат на тестовом фрейме.

1. Размножаем первый фрейм, соединяя исходный и модифицированный (в котором колонки first и second поменяны местами). Это для того, чтобы в колонке first были все возможные значения.
2. Группируем по first и делаем вспомогательную колонку c рангом по
   count (в обратном порядке) - самые большие значения будут иметь
   ранги 1 и 2.
3. Соединяем фрейм 2 с фреймом 1 (отфильтрованным по рангу до 3) через 'resource_id' - 'first' и
   выворачиваем результат, чтобы колонками стал ранг, а значениями -
   колонка second.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'pairs': [(551, 566), (515, 551), (489, 551), (523, 551), (566, 794)],
                    'first': [566, 551, 551, 551, 794],
                    'second': [551, 515, 489, 523, 566],
                    'count': [797, 417, 311, 304, 290]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'resource_id': list(range(356, 1201))})

df1 = pd.concat([df1, df1.rename(columns={'second': 'first', 'first': 'second'})])
df1['biggest'] = df1.groupby('first')['count'].rank(ascending=False).astype(int)
df = df2.merge(df1[df1.biggest.lt(3)], left_on='resource_id', right_on='first').pivot(index='resource_id', columns='biggest', values='second').reset_index()
print(df)
```

```
biggest  resource_id      1      2
0                489  551.0    NaN
1                515  551.0    NaN
2                523  551.0    NaN
3                551  566.0  515.0
4                566  551.0  794.0
5                794  566.0    NaN
```